# Twig LoaderError: Template is not defined

Tags: theming

When I try to edit a page to upload 2 documents, I get an error.

Procedure: I edit the node, upload the first document. Then I insert a new field to upload the second document. However, the second field does not appear and I get the following error message in dblog:

> "Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template
>   "themes/bootstrap_sbv/layout/sbv-personenseite-layout.html.twig" is
>   not defined. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 10 of
>   webpath/docroot/modules/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig).

I have tried to include the layout in the "ds-entity-view.html.twig" file.

```
{% include "/themes/bootstrap_sbv/layouts/sbv-personenseite-layout.html.twig" %}
```

But it doesn't work.

Curiously, everything works on the local environment. Only on the test and production environment I get the error. I have a custom theme on my Drupalsite.

Comment: Can you ensure that your template is present in the right location for non-working environments?

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but instead of using an absolute path `{% include '/theme/my_theme/dummy...' %}` you can use a module's or theme's machine name as namespace `{% include '@my_theme/dummy...' %}` - this way you are safe if your modules/themes are split in `.../contrib/...` (from drupal.org) and `.../custom/...` (own code) sub-folders

Comment: I tried to add `{% include "@bootstrap_sbv/layouts/sbv-personenseite-layout.html.twig" %}` but get the following error
`Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@bootstrap_sbv/layouts/sbv-detail-page-layout.html.twig" is not defined in "modules/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig" at line 1. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 142 of /webpath/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ChainLoader.php).`

Comment: @Zeroplexer after giving it a thought I notice that the error cames from DS module. It seems to me that is possible that you are using custom layouts and you have a typo on the template route for that layout. Check this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/162482/custom-layouts-with-the-display-suite-module

Comment: Note that all Twig templates should always reside inside the `/templates` subfolder of your theme/module.

Comment: @Hudri Thanks a lot. I have move all Twig templates in the `/templates` folder. And changed the path in my `layouts.yml` file. Now I don't get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the templates to the Templates folder `themes/THEMENAME/templates` has solved the problem. I also had to change the path in the `THEMENAME.layouts.yml`

Comment: Please check your answer as "correct answer" so can be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to `@my_theme` syntax it refers to `themes/my_theme/templates` folder while the desired template is located into `themes/my_theme/layouts` folder.

So what I suggest is to use a relative path to include the template, something like that:

`{% include '../../../themes/bootstrap_sbv/layouts/sbv-personenseite-layout.html.twig' %}`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work I get this error: `Twig\Error\LoaderError: Template "@bootstrap_sbv/layouts/sbv-detail-page-layout.html.twig" is not defined in "modules/ds/templates/ds-entity-view.html.twig" at line 1. in Twig\Loader\ChainLoader->getCacheKey() (line 142 of /webpath/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/ChainLoader.php).`

Comment: Great advice!  
By writing the absolute path, then swapping-in `@my_theme` for `/themes/my_theme/templates`, I got what I came here for.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when I wanted to use a database state, which was created with Version 10.2.2 and my Drupal instance was on 10.1.2.

Updating fixed the issue.